# Ansible, saving list of hosts into a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, ansible

I have a playbook where I am first running a SQL statement to get a list of hosts from a database. I then save that list into a variable and want to run the next set of tasks over this list of hosts. But I am not sure how to do this or if it is even possible to dynamically define the hosts into an Ansible variable?

Below is a snippet of my code and what I am trying to do.

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - name: Get list of hosts
    command: sqlcmd -d testDB -q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT DISTINCT HostName FROM Servers" -S "Central_Server" -h -1
    register: sql_servers

- hosts: '{{ sql_servers.stdout_lines }}'
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
........

other tasks

........
```

In the above code, I am trying to save the list of hosts into the **sql_servers** variables and want to run the 2nd set of my playbook over those hosts.

Comment: Not an Ansible user here so I don't have an answer for your question. But you probably want to use sqlcmd's `-Q` parameter instead of `-q`. The former terminates after the query completes, the latter does not.

Comment: Consider changing the title. Your list of hosts has already been saved in the variable ``sql_servers.stdout_lines``. What you want is to run this list of hosts in the next play.

Comment: Although @VladimirBotka's answer below is indeed a direct and good answer to your question, you might want to have a look at [dynamic inventories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#developing-inventory). It might be more suitable on the long run if you have a lot of servers referenced in you mysql db.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Thanks for the suggestion, I made the change in my code now.

Comment: @Zeitounator: I did see the dynamic inventories option and will definitely look into utilizing that for the future. At this time though, what was suggested below works for us since it's quick and easy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running the play with `hosts: all`. This implicates that there might be more hosts and, as a result, more lists of sql_servers too. Let's concatenate the lists. For example, whatever the source of the lists might be, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
srv1 sql_servers='["a", "b"]'
srv2 sql_servers='["c", "a"]'
srv3 sql_servers='["e", "b"]'
```

the play

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        srvs: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                  map('extract', hostvars, 'sql_servers')|
                  flatten|unique }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  srvs:
  - a
  - b
  - c
  - e
```

Now, use [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html#ansible-builtin-add-host-add-a-host-and-alternatively-a-group-to-the-ansible-playbook-in-memory-inventory) and create group *sql_servers*

```yaml
    - add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item }}"
        groups: sql_servers
      loop: "{{ srvs }}"
      run_once: true
```

Use this group in the next play. The complete simplified playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item }}"
        groups: sql_servers
      loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts|
                map('extract', hostvars, 'sql_servers')|
                flatten|unique }}"
      run_once: true

- hosts: sql_servers
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - a
  - b
  - c
  - e
```

Fit the control flow to your needs.